# Grafana and cert-manager on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I would like to deploy the `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart on a GKE cluster using the following values:

```yaml
grafana:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - grafana.example.com
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-issuer"
      acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: true
    tls:
      - secretName: "tls-grafana"
        hosts:
          - grafana.example.com
```

The following is the `ClusterIssuer` used for `cert-manager`:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: changeme@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-secret
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

The `grafana` ingress is created by no IP address is assigned to it by GCP.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClusterIssuer` has no bearing on whether the Grafana ingress is created or not. If your ingress is not getting an IP, you have no ingress controller configured on your cluster.

Alternatively do a `kubectl describe` on the ingress and look at the events section at the bottom of the output. Sometimes, there will be messages there that might tell you where you need to look.